# Getting null pointer exception while using var inside mocked class

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

I am writing unit tests for my play app. Some data in app is rarely changed needs to be accessed frequently. So, I am fetching it in start and storing it in a hashmap.

```
var inMemQuestion:Map[Long,QuestionSchema.Question] = {
    println("Getting all questions from DB.....")
    Await.result(listAll, Duration.Inf).map(a => a.id->a).toMap
  }
```

In my methods I'm using data from here instead of db.

But when I try to mock this for unit testing my methods like this:

```
val sampleQsn = QuestionSchema.Question(9.toLong,"1 or 2",7.toLong,4.toLong,Some(1.0),Some(false),new java.sql.Timestamp(1599545742),new java.sql.Timestamp(1599552379))
val questionsRepo = mock[QuestionRepository]
when(questionsRepo.inMemQuestion(9)).thenReturn( // null pointer error in this line
  sampleQsn
)
```

I'm getting null pointer error. Can anyone help me in resolving that?

Comment: Since question repo is mocked. All of its members are left as null unless explicitly provided with a mocked implementation. This means, `questionsRepo.inMemQuestion` is `null`.

Comment: @sarveshseri yeah I'm trying to provide implementation for input 9 and output as sampleQsn as when thenReturn clause.

Comment: `inMemQuestion` is not a `method`. Its a `value member`.

Comment: @sarveshseri I've tried to assign value to it also.. and I get same exception. Main focus is how to solve this error so if i try to get value at key 9 i get `sampleQsn`

Comment: 1. Do not use `var` 2. Compose rather than `Await`